# Submitting my app to the store without the intention of selling it

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm building an iOS game that will have both singleplayer and multiplayer modes.  I'm building the game in two different phases, one for singleplayer and then a second for multiplayer.  The singleplayer phase is complete and it's completely shippable.  I was thinking about submitting it to the iTunes store before I implement the multiplayer mode so if it gets rejected for any reason, I can fix those issues ahead of time.  However, if it gets approved, I don't plan to release it until I finish the multiplayer mode and submit it as an update.

Is this a good/bad idea?

Do other people do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better you complete the application and then submit it, and app can get rejected for any unknown reason - So I would say just complete the application and submit it. If you know for sure that your app is going to get rejected - then you can submit the app in single player and set the release date to after one month or even a year and complete the multi player mode.

Comment: thanks, vivanaranha.  just curious, what reason would one have to submit an app that they know will be rejected?

Comment: I made a few Fart Apps a long time back, and I knew they would get rejected - But there was one period when Apple was accepting them. SO you never know what reason they would reject or accept... Apple changes their rules everyday

Comment: are you sure this is still the case?  the last two apps I built were rejected the first time I submitted them and they both came back with a clear list of reasons why they were rejected.  Once I addressed those issues, they were accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your release date infinitely long. This way when it is approved, no one will see it. Then you can kill the app if you want after it is approved.

Comment: Some people are saying you can't submit an update if the previous version is in the "approved and awaiting develper release" state.

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe its a little tricky, but the way I have handled that issue is to release it to the store, and then immediately pull it out. Usually it takes a few mins for the app to appear on the store once you release it. So you may chose to do it this way. (Not sure if there is any other way to go about it)